# Assertion error when trying to include textures SDL2 c++

Tags: c++, sdl-2, glew

I made a graphic engine with SDL2, and when I add a texture, it displays an error:

[image: Screenshot]

However, if i dont include textures, everything works fine.

I also have reasons to belive, that the error is connected to the IDE, because I read other questions.

My IDE: VS 2017 pro

**The code**

run()

```
void maingame::run()
{
    initSystems();
    _sprite.init(-1.0f, -1.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f);
    _enemyTexture = ImageLoader::loadPNG("textures/jimmyJump_pack/PNG/CharacterRight_Standing.png");
    gameLoop();
}
```

run() method gets called by main() func

The initialization of the sprite:

```
void targetSprite::init(float x, float y, float width, float height)
{
    _x = x;
    _y = y;
    _width = width;
    _height = height;

    if (_vboID == 0) {
        glGenBuffers(1, &_vboID);
    }
    Vertex vertexData[6];
    //1st
    vertexData[0].setPos(_x + _width, _y + _height);
    vertexData[0].setUV(1.0f, 1.0f);

    vertexData[1].setPos(_x, _y + _height);
    vertexData[1].setUV(0.0f, 1.0f);

    vertexData[2].setPos(_x, _y);
    vertexData[2].setUV(0.0f, 0.0f);

    //2nd

    vertexData[3].setPos(_x, _y);
    vertexData[3].setUV(0.0f, 0.0f);

    vertexData[4].setPos(_x + _width, _y);
    vertexData[4].setUV(1.0f, 0.0f);

    vertexData[5].setPos(_x + _width, _y + _height);
    vertexData[5].setUV(1.0f, 1.0f);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        vertexData[i].setColor(127, 127, 255, 255);
    }

    vertexData[1].setColor(255, 0, 255, 255);
    vertexData[4].setColor(0, 255, 255, 255);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexData), vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboID);
}
```

I posted this because I belive the error is in here.

But it is not necessary, because this same code runs whitout textures.

On line 10 "Vertex" is a struct.

I tried changing build from debug to release, but then I got problems with .dll files.

**EDIT:**

This calls the error in vector:

```
GLTexture ImageLoader::loadPNG(std::string filePath)
{
    GLTexture texture = {};
    std::vector<unsigned char> out;
    unsigned long width;
    unsigned long height;
    std::vector<unsigned char> in;
    if (IOManager::readFileToBuffer(filePath, in) == false) { //read the texture to buffer
        fatalError2("FTB 1");
    }
    int errorCode = decodePNG(out, width, height, &(in[0]), in.size()); //error line
    if (errorCode != 0) {
        fatalError2("DPNG 1: " + std::to_string(errorCode));
    }

    glGenTextures(1, &(texture.id));
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.id);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &(out[0]));
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    texture.width = width;
    texture.height = height;

    return texture;
}
```

Line 25, then goes back to run(), main(), and then opens a "sdl_windows_main.c not found" window.

So i guess the question is where that file is located?

**EDIT 2**

the readFileToBuffer() method, i belive responsible for filling the "in" vector

```
bool IOManager::readFileToBuffer(std::string filePath, std::vector<unsigned char> buffer)
{
    std::ifstream file(filePath, std::ios::binary);
    if (file.fail()) {
        perror(filePath.c_str());
        return false;
    }
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    int fileSize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    fileSize = fileSize - file.tellg();
    buffer.resize(fileSize);
    file.read((char *)&(buffer[0]), fileSize);
    file.close();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: When you get the assert, choose retry to debug and look at the callstack to find exactly where, in your code, the error came from. You are addressing a vector out of range, and none of the code you've shown uses a vector so it's not the problem. Consider a [mcve] so we can see all of the code that might be the issue. If you don't solve it by looking in the debugger you may find it by narrowing down your code to something small and presentable here.

Comment: In the error box the second button is "Retry". When you press it when running application under debugger it will open the failed line in the library code but on the bottom there should be "Call Stack" window which will allow you to see the calls from your code that lead to this error. By clicking on the lines you can navigate to your code at the failing state and inspect the variables. The error you posted is about accessing `std::vector` via `operator []` with invalid index and the code you posted contains no `std::vector`.

Comment: it opens a "vector" file on line 1733. it also prints out  on the debugger: "Unhandled exception at 0x0F7EE906 (ucrtbased.dll) in GameProject.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal."

Comment: I know, you should navigate to the calling code in the "Call stack" window to see why it is invoked with incorrect index.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: If `in.size()` returns 0, meaning you have an empty vector, then `&(in[0])` will cause that assert. The callstack will show you the exact line where the error occurs, please highlight it in some way.

Comment: It shows the line you found, and then run() method, main() func and "sdl_windows_main.c not found" page

Comment: Did a bit of error catching, ```in.size()``` does return 0, so in[] is an empty vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to pass "buffer" by reference

```
bool IOManager::readFileToBuffer(std::string filePath, std::vector<unsigned char>&buffer)
{
    std::ifstream file(filePath, std::ios::binary);
    if (file.fail()) {
        perror(filePath.c_str());
        return false;
    }
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    int fileSize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    fileSize = fileSize - file.tellg();
    buffer.resize(fileSize);
    file.read((char *)&(buffer[0]), fileSize);
    file.close();
    return true;
}
´´´
```